# Prove that the product of two trigonometric polynomials is also trigonometric polynomial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials

EDIT: wrote new thing, how now?
$P\left(t\right)=\sum _{n=-N}^Na_n\cdot e^{int}$
$Q\left(t\right)=\sum _{m=-N}^Nb_m\cdot e^{imt}$
$P\left(t\right)\cdot Q\left(t\right)=\sum _{m=-N}^Nb_m\cdot e^{imt}\sum _{n=-N}^:a_n\cdot e^{int}$
Thus, it is:
$\sum _{n=-N}^N\sum _{m=-N}^Na_nb_m\cdot e^{i\left(n+m\right)t}$
From here I am stuck, but I will slowly solve it.

Comment: Your nested sums have the same index variable. Not a good idea. And your $d_n$ depends on $t$, so your proof is moot. The core of the proof is $e^{pit}e^{qit}=e^{nit}$ with $n=p+q$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Hi, I dont understand what you mean? products of who? z with who?

Comment: About the indexes, so you say, I should make one series from $-N$ to +$N$ and the other from $-M$ to $+M$? and then what? the problem is we didnt learn how to combine series into one. ( especially one with different indexes )

Comment: You can assume $N=M$ by inserting $0$ coefficients if needed

Comment: Oh yea, I did it, By my message above, I meant what I did up there, my bad in explanation ( bad english )

Comment: The trigonmetric polynomial is a linear combination of the monomials $x\mapsto e^{ikx}.$ The product of two monomials $e^{ikx}$ and $e^{ilx}$ is the monomial $e^{i(k+l)x}.$ By linearity the product of two trigonmetric polynomials is a trigonmetric polynomial. The reasoning goes along the same lines as the fact  that the product of two algebraic polynomial is a polynomial.

Comment: yea but the problem is to prove that the product is polynomial.
But okay, I will try, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No.

First, I think you mean $p(t)$ and $q(t)$, since you are using $t$ in the sums, right?

Next, I'm sure you intend for the coefficients to be constants, not functions of the independent variable, so you can't possibly put $d_n\equiv \sum\limits_{n=-N}^Nc_n e^{int}$ because this expression isn't constant (it depends on $t$).

As a hint, try distributing each term of one series over the other series and collecting the resulting product terms that have the same factor $e^{int}$ ($n=-2N, \ldots, 2N$).

Comment: Okay Edited.
Now, regarding what you said, about $d_n$ yea, to be honest, I understand, it is not costannt, so I cant use it. about the distribution, what do you mean? I tried doing for example n=3, and saw I have 9 multiplication.

Comment: I hope I dont need to use anything related to orthonormal basis \ inner product, yea?

Comment: Yes, but you can tell which terms can be combined. For example, $a_jb_k$  and $a_{j-1}b_{k+1}$ both go with $e^{(j+k)it}$ in the product, and there are many others. The pairs that go with $e^{nit}$ are those whose subscripts add up to $n$, right?

Comment: Really? I am trying to thing how you can get to this.
It seems like its related to the binomial theorem... I really hope not.

Comment: I am thinking maybe about cauchy product, but I cant tell if that is what your are telling me.. cus from your example it is different.

Comment: I think it's exactly like that. You're just collecting like terms ahead of time.

Comment: Really? I will try, regarding the subcripts, can you tell me what it is? tried google translate it and it said to me like subcribor ( from youtube for example ), my english is not at its best

Comment: Just saw you edited, my bad english dont really understand what you mean by collecting like terms ahead of time? sorry

Comment: It's just because the subscript matches the exponent. Pick a power (say $P$) between $-2N$ and $2N$ write down all the pairs whose product gives you a power with $P$. Then repeat that for all possible such powers, and you are done.

Comment: Yea but I cant understand what do you mean by that. if n=m=$\frac P 2$ so I will get it, if I undestand it well.